# Is it possible to view the logic/code behind a method of a python module?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the OpenID module as part of a flask application.

I've been looking in the module directory to see which methods are accessible, but was wondering if it's possible to see the code/logic behind the methods themselves. If so, how?

is there a similar command to dir(oid) for this?

Comment: Check the source code online?

Comment: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-openid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually find the source file for any given module by looking at the `help` output.

For example:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jan 10 2014, 11:23:15)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import collections

>>> help(collections)
Help on module collections:

NAME
    collections

FILE
    //anaconda/lib/python2.7/collections.py
...
```

From here you can open the file and view the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a look at your python installation/virtualenv "lib" folder

For example Flask src can be found at:

```
(pythondir)\Lib\site-packages\flask
```

Or online:

[flask](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask)

[flask-openid](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-openid)